# Pass folder containing 18000 email text files into function to extract all emails and subject in text

Tags: python, regex

I defined a function with which I want to extract email and store it in a list, and also to extract subject from a folder having numerous emails as text file. The function is:

```
def preprocess(text):
    em =[]
    st =""
    for i in re.findall(r'[\w\-\.]+@[\w\.-]+\b', text):
        temp =[]
        temp = i.split('@')[1]
        temp = temp.split('.')
    
        if 'com' in temp:
            temp.remove('com')
        for i in temp:
            if len(i) >2:
                em.append(i)
    for i in em:
        st +=i
        st += " "
    return em,st
```

To pass each text file in above function, I did:

```
os.chdir(path)

myFiles = glob.glob('*.txt')
print(type(myFiles))
for text in myFiles:
    email_list,subject = preprocess(text)
```

The output I am getting is an empty `email_list` and an empty `subject`, but when I pass a single text file, the function is giving output. How do I pass all text files from a folder in the function so that I can extract the email and subject from each text file?

Comment: When are you reading the contents of the file? At the moment it looks like you are calling the function with the path of the file.

Comment: thats what i want to know

Answer (score 0):

you can open a single file as

```py
with open(path) as fh:
    # work with fh here
```

File-likes are iterable by-lines, so you may be able to find the email that way

```py
results = {}
for path in paths:
    results[path] = {}
    with open(path) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            if subject := test_for_subject(line):
                results[path]["subject"] = subject
                continue  # try the next line
            # emails test
            # consider breaking if subject and emails collected or at some known point in email
```

Comment: thank you for your reply ,i have to use the function which i wrote above because have to edit it later for preprocessing text,i have problem is in my desktop i have a folder in which there are 18000 emails as tect file ,how can i use that folder or pass it to the function which i defined